# How to get a random unicode character in objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unicode, appkit

I was wondering how to get a random Unicode character so that every time this is run it generates a different value. This is what I have so far to get a character:

```
    NSFont *arialUnicode = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] 
    fontWithFamily:@"Arial Unicode MS"
    traits:0 
    weight:5 
    size:dirtyRect.size.height*0.6];

    NSGlyph *glyphs = (NSGlyph *)malloc(sizeof(NSGlyph) * 1); 

    CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters((CTFontRef)arialUnicode, (const UniChar *)L"\u2668", (CGGlyph *)glyphs, 1);
```

It is adapted from a drawing tutorial my friend sent me: http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/01/advanced-drawing-using-appkit.html

Quite a nice tutorial actually :)

But I want to know how to use any character as opposed to just the floral heart. I have found that buy changing the value of 2668 to some other value in the line:

`CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters((CTFontRef)arialUnicode, (const UniChar *)L"\u2668", (CGGlyph *)glyphs, 1);`

I can make it change character but i want to automate this so that it automatically chooses different characters.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want a random character, something like

```
UniChar uc = arc4random() % (0xffffu + 1);        
CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters((CTFontRef)arialUnicode, &uc, (CGGlyph *)glyphs, 1);
```

But depending on what you are trying to do

- There are much easier ways to display text in Cocoa, particularly NSTextField
- There are so many characters in Unicode it's highly unlikely a single font will contain all the glyphs.

Do you really want a random unicode code point or do you want to select from a subset of the available characters?  See http://www.unicode.org/charts/ to get an idea of just how much Unicode covers.

Comment: in addition to the problems you've stated, not all those values are going to be valid code points (e.g. see surrogate ranges) or assigned code points. Some of them are going to be control characters or [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). [UnicodeData.txt](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) defines the latest assigned code points and their classifications. There are versions of the document for whatever Unicode version the OS/framework supports.

Comment: @McDowell Very true- I took this as a "how to generate a random UniChar" question. I guess only the OP knows what they are trying to accomplish, but selecting a random code point likely won't give the best results.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot for that. That is seriously great. That is exactly what i wanted. I'll adapt the first line to only get unicode characters within a certain range and then i'll adapt the code from the drawing tutorial to randomly change colours. Then i'll have a random icon generator. Thanks a lot for that. Really helpful